# .NET 6 Application Logs are in JSON format after migration from .NET Core 3.1 (Docker)

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

I recently updated my **.NET Core** REST API from **3.1 to 6.0**.
When I run the App locally without Docker in development or release configuration the logs are formatted as always:

[image]

When running the App as **Docker container, the logs become transformed to JSON**. This just appeared after the migration to .Net 6.

[image]

How can I get back to the standard logging format in the Docker environment?

Comment: A lot has changed since the linked answer. The formatter type can change through configuration or code. There are built-in methods for each of the predefined formatters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The change was made in .NET 5, not 6. In .NET Core 3.1 the Console log format was fixed. In .NET 5 [this is now customizable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter) with 3 predefined formatters: Simple (the old one), Systemd and Json (the default). It's possible to create a custom formatter.

As the docs show, it's possible to use the Simple formatter by using the `AddSimpleConsole` method instead of `AddConsole`:

```
    using ILoggerFactory loggerFactory =
        LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
            builder.AddSimpleConsole(options =>
            {
                options.IncludeScopes = true;
                options.SingleLine = true;
                options.TimestampFormat = "hh:mm:ss ";
            }));
```

There are similar methods for the other two formatters: `AddSystemdConsole` and `AddJsonConsole`.

It's possible to [set the formatter through configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter#set-formatter-with-configuration) :

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        },
        "Console": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Information",
                "Microsoft": "Warning",
                "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
            },
            "FormatterName": "json",
            "FormatterOptions": {
                "SingleLine": true,
                "IncludeScopes": true,
                "TimestampFormat": "HH:mm:ss ",
                "UseUtcTimestamp": true,
                "JsonWriterOptions": {
                    "Indented": true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Finally it's possible to create a completely new formatter by inheriting from `ConsoleFormatter` and overriding the `Write` method :

```
public sealed class CustomFormatter : ConsoleFormatter, IDisposable
{
   ...

    public override void Write<TState>(
        in LogEntry<TState> logEntry,
        IExternalScopeProvider scopeProvider,
        TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        string? message =
            logEntry.Formatter?.Invoke(
                logEntry.State, logEntry.Exception);

        if (message is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        CustomLogicGoesHere(textWriter);
        textWriter.WriteLine(message);
    }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Weird, if I set "FormatterName": "simple" in `appsettings.json` as suggested above, I get a prettyprinted JSON format but I don't get the original .NET Core 3.0 style format. Anyone had luck with this?